# Drop down menu overlapped by lower divs

Tags: css

The issue can be found on my test site: http://udkcf.geekgirlcoding.com/

I created a drop-down menu (the gray box on top). When I expand the menu, the menu items are overlapped by either the branding div or the site content. I tried setting/changing the z-index value, but with no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **'z-index'**
>   ...
>   For a positioned box, the 'z-index' property specifies:
>
> The stack level of the box in the current stacking context.
>   Whether the box establishes a stacking context.
>   Values have the following meanings:
>
> - <integer>
>     This integer is the stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context. The box also establishes a new stacking context.
> - auto
>     The stack level of the generated box in the current stacking context is 0. The box does not establish a new stacking context unless it is the root element.
>
> http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-z-index

All of the surrounding elements will have a `z-index` of **0**, meaning that they don't define a new stacking order and will stack in the order they appear.

You can therefore simply apply a `z-index` of **1** to take the element in question out of the natural stacking order.

This will tell the browser that you want that element to be above every other element

- **unless** there are any following elements with the same `z-index` value
- **or** there are any elements, which may come before or after, which have a **higher** `z-index` value.

```
.dl-menuwrapper {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

[image: screenshot of solution]

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in your stylesheet.

```
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, footer, header, hgroup, main, nav, section, summary {
  display: block;
  z-index: -999;
  position: relative;
}
```